# Different div generated in production

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-flex-layout

We have an Angular 4 app with Angular Material that seems to have different HTML generated once we run the website in production mode. We are using [angular/flex-layout](https://github.com/angular/flex-layout) for layout, and webpack for bundling etc. As an example of the difference locally and prod:

Local:

```
<div class="mat-input-table"> 
<!----> 
<div class="mat-input-infix"> 
   <button type="button" class="mat-datepicker-toggle" aria-label="Open calendar"></button>
          <input formcontrolname="arrivalDate" mdinput="" placeholder="Arrival" aria-expanded="false" aria-haspopup="true" aria-owns="md-datepicker-0" class="mat-input-element ng-pristine ng-valid ng-touched" id="md-input-1">
          <span class="mat-input-placeholder-wrapper"> <!----><label class="mat-input-placeholder mat-float" for="md-input-1">  Arrival <!----> </label> </span> </div> 
<!----> 
</div>
```

Prod:

```
    <div class="mat-input-flex">
    <!---->
    <div class="mat-input-infix">
           <button class="mat-datepicker-toggle" type="button" aria-label="Open calendar"></button>
                  <input class="mat-input-element ng-pristine ng-valid ng-touched" formcontrolname="arrivalDate" mdinput="" placeholder="Arrival" aria-expanded="false" aria-haspopup="true" aria-owns="md-datepicker-0" id="md-input-1" aria-invalid="false">
                  <span class="mat-input-placeholder-wrapper"><!----><label class="mat-input-placeholder ng-tns-c14-1 mat-float" for="md-input-1">Arrival 
<!----></label></span></div>
    <!----></div>
```

Excuse the formatting, but as you can see the top level div in these blocks has different classes assigned to it in the different environments. This class is not something that we have in our HTML, but is generated on output of the project. Any clues, ideas, thoughts welcome here, we are really unfamiliar with an issue like this.

EDIT:
The HTML that is generating these outputs:

```
<!-- Arrival Date -->
<div fxFlex="100" fxFlex.gt-sm="20" class="form-group datepicker-container gutter-right-gt-sm" [class.has-error]="formErrors.arrivalDate">
       <div fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="center center" class="input-icon-container datepicker">
           <md-input-container>
               <button [mdDatepickerToggle]="arrivalDatepicker"></button>
               <input mdInput 
                      [mdDatepicker]="arrivalDatepicker" 
                      [mdDatepickerFilter]="minArrivalFilter" 
                      formControlName="arrivalDate" 
                      placeholder="Arrival"/>
           </md-input-container>
           <md-datepicker #arrivalDatepicker flex='auto' [touchUi]="false"></md-datepicker>
      </div>
       <span *ngIf="formErrors.arrivalDate">{{formErrors.arrivalDate}}</span></div>
```

Comment: Please show us the template code that generates this html

Comment: Template HTML added.

Answer (score 0):

flex-layout is a responsive temaplate, whish has different styles for different viewports and devices. It means if you have a slight change in the settings, e.g., compatibility mode or differetn browsers, the classes might change. That being said, the UI behaviour should be the same.

Comment: But this is the same browser, same size, everything identical, yet a different class is generated. I cannot find much documentation on `mat-input-table` vs `mat-input-flex` either, so it's harder to diagnose the switching between the two.